# Redis scan's weird ghost

Tags: node.js, redis

I'm relatively new to redis, and facing a weird issue. As the documentation said to avoid using keys I'm trying to switch to Scan.

My keys are all stored on the following scheme :

```
mongo_id:jwt
```

For now I have only 2 keys so **this seems not to be a COUNT issue**.
I was able to get all user's keys by using the scan command but for some reason some results (1 from two, the ghost !) are no longer showing up.

```
 keys * // In redis CLI 
 1) "598318bbde0928235a8279b3:firstJWT" // here it is
 2) "598318bbde0928235a8279b3:secondJWT" 

 TYPE 598318bbde0928235a8279b3:firstJWT
 hash

 TYPE 598318bbde0928235a8279b3:secondJWT
 hash

 SCAN 2 MATCH '598318bbde0928235a8279b3:*' COUNT 10 // 2 is the cursor
 1) "0"
 2) 1) "598318bbde0928235a8279b3:secondJWT"
 // where did the first result go ??
```

Stuck on this for a while now, any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all the elements you need to start with [the cursor set to `0`](https://redis.io/commands/scan#scan-basic-usage), not `2`.

> An iteration starts when the cursor is set to 0, and terminates when the cursor returned by the server is 0.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! kind of confused the cursor and the db.